# Where to find updated Magento API Docs?

Tags: magento-1.7

Just downloaded the community edition of Magento (v1.7.0.2) and wanted to know where there was a fully documented API for this? I looked at http://docs.magentocommerce.com/ but I don't think this is up to date and a few things "smell wrong" in that in some code was looking at the API docs informed me that a method returned "void" when in fact it did return an object! (also it was generated with PHPDoc v1.4.3 which I don't think has been around for a while) I was thinking of generating the docs myself but the source code is not adequately marked-up so I don't think it would help much!

Thanks in advance!